# Uniform prior: Is this description of the function correct?

Tags: bayesian

I was learning about Bayesian Parameter Estimation when I came across Uniform prior.
I saw the answers to this  [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419529/can-anyone-give-a-concrete-example-to-illustrate-what-is-an-uniform-prior) for some insight into it.
In the source I'm referring to, this is how the function is described:
[image]

Doesn't this suggest that for any θ, P(θ) = 1? How is that possible? Have I misunderstood the description?

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I suggest drawing out that function, say on $(-1,2)$. Does that look like a uniform distribution to you?

Comment: You can see a plot of $P$ in the second figure of my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075/919.  The first figure plots the corresponding distribution function (its CDF).  Reading between the lines, I would guess you might be misinterpreting $P$ as giving probabilities.  It doesn't: it's a *density.*  For the distinction, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220.  In fact, the *probability* of any single value of $\theta$ is zero.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730.

Comment: Can you expand on your background? Like, how much you know about the differences between probability distribution, density function, cdf...

Answer (score 1):

This $P(\theta)$ is the probability density, therefore
$$
\text{Probability of finding } a \leq \theta \leq b = \int_a^b d\theta P(\theta).
$$

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question...

Comment: OP asked how is it possible for any $\theta\in[0,1]$ the $P(\theta)$ to be 1. That's why I think she/he took it as a probability instead of probability density.

Comment: I can see that, OK.